# TF30042: The database is full

Tags: tfs

Today team reports an error of TFS 2012:

> TF30042: The database is full. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator

Event Log from data base server:

> MSSQLSERVER: Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.tbl_NotificationQueue'.'PK_tbl_NotificationQueue' in database 'Tfs_Real-Time collection' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.
>
> MSSQLServerOLAPService: An error occurred while writing a trace event to the file, \?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Log\FlightRecorderCurrent.trc.

The C driver is no space available to use.

Could anyone give some suggestions?

Comment: Clear the transaction log on the database. Delete some files on the C:-disk. Do you own the TFS-server?

Comment: If C drive is full, why don't you move databases on another drive? It would even be possible to move them to another SQL server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The tfs topology is not designed by us.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Option 1: Clean the drive to free up space. Delete transaction logs, look for extraneous test case attachments, build drops checked into source that sort of thing.

Option 2: Get a bigger hard drive.

Comment: Yes, actually we have a strategy to backup the sql log and the location is D drive. And also the d drive is full too now. So we move the backed files ad d drive and start backup again. And the issue is fixed now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you use MTM check out the Test Attachment Cleaner in the TFS Power Tools: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f  This can really free up a lot of space.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the table "tbl_JobHistory" had become much too large (>7.5GB). As a result, the 10GB of the SQL-Express database were fully utilized.
With Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio you can easily view the largest tables: "Reports" > "Standard Reports" > "Disk Usage by Top Tables".
I deleted the data in "tbl_JobHistory" and then shrinked the database.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6cI3.png)